# How to call a method every 2 hours in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer

How would it be possible to call a method every 2 hours in C#

For example possibly make a click event occur every 2 hours

Comment: Could you add some more context? Is it a single long-running app, or one that will be started and stopped?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Timer [Timer.Tick Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick.aspx)

1. Add `Timer` component to your form.
2. Set interval to 7200000 ms (2 x 60 x 60 x 1000)
3. Subscribe to `Tick` event.
4. Call the method that you need to call. For example:

   ```
   private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      button1_Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);
   }
   ```

I assumed you are using Windows Forms.

If you are using WPF, there is `DispatcherTimer` class.

Comment: @djacobson - thank you. Something is wrong with my math today :).

Comment: Did it just now, works like a charm, actually suprised how easy is was, thanks again!

Comment: @AlexAza - Thanks it resolved our problem too. But I am still wondering if we can make it configurable like user have to set the duration lets say user set the duration of 2-days now what to do here? Do we need to convert 2-days into millisecond i.e. (86400 000 X 2) ? Isn't there any other way like Timer check that this is the date configured to start and this is the current date and if difference is two days so, lets start to do the things?

Answer (score 5):

Make an app which runs on a scheduled task if possible, it can then be set to call the method every 2 hours.

Answer (score 1):

If your program uses forms, then a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdh6857z.aspx) can be added and configured to create a [Timer.Tick Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick.aspx) every two hours (keep in mind Timer.Interval is in milliseconds).  You can then use the Timer.Tick Event handler to call a method of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.castleproject.org/Tools.Scheduler.ashx